# What is the proper way to implement a REST API for multi-step registration form in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: api, asp.net-core

I need to develop a REST API for a new user registration form which consists of 2 steps. Step 1 validates email and password requirements. The data gets saved into the database on Step 2 after the user specifies valid country and region. What is the recommended approach in such scenarios? Using different endpoints for step 1 and 2, like /users/password and /users/location? Using a single endpoint, but having some info about the current step as part of the Dto? Anything else?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Could you please share a more details what you are up to now, would be great if you can share your `code snippet` so that it would be more specific what you are struggling with.

Answer (score 0):

Hi 
you can use both of the options i my self used both of them but in my experience using a multi endpoint is more maintainable. And also it good match for single-responsibility principle (SRP)